# How to access nested values in json

Tags: python, api, scopus

I am trying to get data from scopus using api and python. I query using python module requests.
The response of the query gets me a json with values like the following.

{
    "search-results": {
        "opensearch:totalResults": "1186741",
        "opensearch:startIndex": "0",
        "opensearch:itemsPerPage": "25",
        "opensearch:Query": {
            "@role": "request",
            "@searchTerms": "all(machine learning)",
            "@startPage": "0"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "@_fa": "true",
                "@ref": "self",
                "@href": "api query",
                "@type": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "@_fa": "true",
                "@ref": "first",
                "@href": "api query",
                "@type": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "@_fa": "true",
                "@ref": "next",
                "@href": "api query",
                "@type": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "@_fa": "true",
                "@ref": "last",
                "@href": "api query",
                "@type": "application/json"
            }
        ],
        "entry": [
            {
                "@_fa": "true",
                "link": [
                    {
                        "@_fa": "true",
                        "@ref": "self",
                        "@href": "https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/85081889595"
                    },
                    {
                        "@_fa": "true",
                        "@ref": "author-affiliation",
                        "@href": "https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/85081889595?field=author,affiliation"
                    },
                    {
                        "@_fa": "true",
                        "@ref": "scopus",
                        "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=85081889595&origin=inward"
                    },
                    {
                        "@_fa": "true",
                        "@ref": "scopus-citedby",
                        "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/inward/citedby.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=85081889595&origin=inward"
                    }
                ],
                "prism:url": "https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/85081889595",
                "dc:identifier": "SCOPUS_ID:85081889595",
                "eid": "2-s2.0-85081889595",
                "dc:title": "Recognizing hotspots in Brief Eclectic Psychotherapy for PTSD by text and audio mining",
                "dc:creator": "Wiegersma S.",
                "prism:publicationName": "European Journal of Psychotraumatology",
                "prism:issn": "20008198",
                "prism:eIssn": "20008066",
                "prism:volume": "11",
                "prism:issueIdentifier": "1",
                "prism:pageRange": null,
                "prism:coverDate": "2020-12-31",
                "prism:coverDisplayDate": "31 December 2020",
                "prism:doi": "10.1080/20008198.2020.1726672",
                "citedby-count": "0",
                "affiliation": [
                    {
                        "@_fa": "true",
                        "affilname": "University of Twente",
                        "affiliation-city": "Enschede",
                        "affiliation-country": "Netherlands"
                    }
                ],
                "prism:aggregationType": "Journal",
                "subtype": "ar",
                "subtypeDescription": "Article",
                "article-number": "1726672",
                "source-id": "21100394256",
                "openaccess": "1",
                "openaccessFlag": true
            },

However, the response is a nested json and I am not able to access the inner elements of it like the keys dc:creator, citedby-count etc.

Can anyone please help me with how to access all parts of it, like author name, cited by, affiliation etc. 
I want to store this result as csv which I can use for further manipulation.

Directly applying

df = pandas.read_json(file name)

doesn't yield correct result format: I get a table like this.

`entry  [{'@_fa': 'true', 'link': [{'@_fa': 'true', '@...
link    [{'@_fa': 'true', '@ref': 'self', '@href': 'ht...
opensearch:Query    {'@role': 'request', '@searchTerms': 'all(mach...
opensearch:itemsPerPage 25
opensearch:startIndex   0
opensearch:totalResults 1186741`

I have also tried the accessing by nested dictionary to list to dictionary method, but at some point, I get stuck.

```
with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as access:
      read_file = json.load(access)
```

…

```
type(read_file)
```

which is a dictionary so I follow syntax of dictionary to access further, and it converts to list at some point and dictionary again.

My main requirement is - **how to create a csv file with column headers which would be tags inside entry tag like dc:identifier, dc:title, dc:creator, citedby-count etc, and values within them ** 
    enter code here

Comment: Show us some sample data, what you have tried so far and what problems you are facing exactly.

Comment: I have edited my question. how to re post it? I am new here and I hope this time it has suffieciient details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
dict_data = json.loads(response)
print(dict_data['key'])
```

Is this what you mean ?